# Generic List Replacement

Tags: c#, list, generics

so I'm trying to set a `list<>` field within an object with a new `list<>`.
this list could be of any type, hence the use of generics.

I get a compile time error, 'cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>` expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`'
Is there anyway to make this work?

```
private void MyGenericMethod<T>(FieldInfo field)
{   
    field.SetValue(obj, new List<T>(newObjectList));    // new List<T> allObjects.ConvertAll<IEnumerable>) ???
}
```

Comment: What is `newObjectList`?

Comment: its the new List<> that I want to put into the field, in this case its global in the class.

Comment: If it's global in the class, then it's not of the correct type - it can't be of type `List<T>`, since the `T` type parameter exists only within the definition and body of this method.

Comment: @user1229895 - if newObjectList is IEnumerable<T> make it List<T> which looks what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: I see what you mean, it was a container to hold the new objects.  I'll possibly look to move it locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with Damien. The problem must be newObjectList, because there's no problem passing a List of generic type to SetValue, as it accepts two arguments of type Object

```
public void SetValue(
Object obj,
Object value
)
```

If you create a new List and populate it with another collection, it will ask for a IEnumerable, so you should try something like

```
field.SetValue(obj, new List<T>(newObjectList as IEnumerable<T>));
```

At least, at compilation time, it will not throw any error

Comment: I forgot about the 'as' keyword.  It solved the compile issue, but I think fundamentally it has problems as the object would need to have many special cases to work for other types. But it does compile now, thanks!